# AsyncStorage with JSON Object in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to pull `json` data after storing it in `AsyncStorage` on an android emulator. I can pull the data inside an async function, but I can't store it in a variable to be used elsewhere in my code

The following code will pull the data, but I cannot call variable `value` any where else in my code:

```
async function getValue(){
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('redditInsights')
    console.log(value)
    return value

  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

If I define a variable like so:  `const insights = getValue()` outside the above function,  it seems to try an define `insights` before the `getValue()` function is finished retrieving the data and so returns it as an empty object

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: are you returning the value? `return value` to the place where `getValue` was called? Or, if you want, instead of a return, create a global variable and assing its value = to `value`

Comment: Tried that,  sorry let me fix the code above. When I define a variable like so: ` const insights = getValue()` it seems to try an define insights before the getValue() function is finished retrieving the data and so returns it as an empty object

Comment: Is it possible to define a global variable inside the async function? How do you do that?

Comment: try with `global.myGlobalVar = value`, then I think you can use this variable anywhere since it is global...

Comment: Are you awaiting the async function getValue?

`const insights = await getValue();`

Comment: Sorry for being away for a minute. Global variables give the same outcome and  I can't use ``await `` outside an ``async`` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const getValue = async () => {
  let value = '';
  try {
   value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('redditInsights')
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
    console.log(error.message);
  }
  return value;
}
```

Comment: I can't use await outside an async function Noor. I get this error: ``` Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function ```